# Visual Studio doesn't build App packages any more

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, hololens

I don't know why but after upgrading Microsoft to the insider preview version. I know, it's always a bad idea to update anything but had to do it to get the new MR Headsets to work...

I downgraded again after visual studio was unable to create any app packages. And it still doesn't work.... tried to repair visual studio and still nothing. I know it's a VS issue because i can't even build older projects which always worked and which i haven't touched.

[image]

And now after reinstalling it tells me that the package is unavailable and that i should install windows10 sdk even tho i installed it 100x already.

Edit: I'm also constantly getting this error:

[image]

And even after installing the file suggested below nothing works.
I don't get my Microsoft keeps building shit that never works..

Comment: i dont know why but same problem is with , i installed vs2015 and vs 2017 both need seprate sdk e.g i have installed 10.0.14393 sdk one for vs2015 and another 10.0.14393 sdk from vs installer if you are not install sdk from vs2017 installer then it is not working for vs2017 and say install missing feature , so try to install that sdk from vs 2017 installer or click on that install button given in screenshot

Comment: i downloaded the sdk like 43times. Also from the installer and from the button given. Unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: from vs2017 installer ?

Comment: Yes, and i'm getting an error that he can't install 'vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi' no idea what that means and when googling it there is no download for it or anything.

I just need to build a goddamm app package for UWP

Comment: This is the link for that component https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572, alternately reinstall vs2017 with admin privilege and also turn off any your strict antivirus

Comment: That link was for x64 it is for x86 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should try the last resort:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio
Use the InstallCleanup.exe to remove all things

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with using visual studio 2017, when doing hololens development, my stable environment is visual studio 2015 Update 3.0.0 and Unity 5.5 0f1. These I know will work together. Also, if you are trying to use the hololens toolkit, you will also have issues with the new versions of Visual Studio. So you will want to take the Dev branch and not master.